# Team Explorer 2008 and MS SCC API?

Tags: tfs, explorer, msscc

I apologize if this seems slightly off-topic, it's more a technical/installation question than it is a programming question, though I bet someone here knows it.

In any case...

I've installed Team Explorer 2008 since we're using TFS here for source control, and now I'm looking at Help and Manual, which has support for source control using MS SCC API. However, Team Explorer/TFS doesn't appear in the available providers for H&M.

My questions are:

1. Does TFS/Team Explorer implement this API?
2. Did I forget to install or configure something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 and you then installed Team Explorer 2008, you might need to go to Options, Source Control to change the source control plug-in to Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.

After this is selected, you should be able to add a current solution to source control or go to View, Team Explorer to open the Team Explorer view and then press the little button with a plus (+) on it to connect to your server and then browse source control to open a shared solution from TFS on your computer.

Interestingly, from Visual Studio 2005 and up, MSSCCI no longer has to be used to talk to version control, but there is another mechanism that the Team Explorers for 2005 and 2008 hook into.

That said, If you want to talk to TFS in an IDE previous to Visual Studio 2005, then you might also need to install the [MSSCCI provider for TFS 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=faeb7636-644e-451a-90d4-7947217da0e7&displaylang=en). This will give you access to TFS for version control in VB6, Visual Studio 2003 etc.

Hope that helps,

Martin.

Comment: Thanks, it was that provider I was looking for.